# Aggregate KStream in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

If I have below records

```
{"A",7}
{"B",10}
{"C",10}
```

Then the aggregation should be

```
{"sum_ABC",27}
```

Then when A is changed to 10
i.e. new message is added

```
{"A",10}
```

It should now calculate as

```
{"sum_ABC",30}


val record: KTable[String, JsonNode] = builder.table("logs",m_consumed)
val aggVal: KTable[String, Double] = record.toStream().groupByKey()
        .reduce(new Reducer[Double]() {
        def apply(val1: Double, val2: Double): Double =
          {
            println(val1)
            val1 + val2
          }
      })
```

This does not work
It keeps on adding the values
and if restarted it directly add 0 + new value.
Till now I have understood I need to use aggregate instead of reduce.
Please guide how to do it . Any links or any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations are always based on keys. Thus, if you want to aggregate over messages with different keys (in your example `A,B,C`) you need to set a new key for all messages to map them to a single key.

Also, to get update semantics, you need to apply the aggregation on a `KTable`. In your example, to transform the `KTable` into a `KStream` (via `toStream()`) and thus, change the semantics from "updates" to "facts".

You should use:

```
KTable record = ...
KTable result = record.groupBy(/* map records that you want to aggregate to the same key*/)
                      .reduce(...).
```